# second iterator property value to first iterator

Tags: struts2

here the first iterators`<s:property value="second iterators <s:property value="heading">`

how to assign

**here is the sample code:**

```
<s:iterator status="one"   value="firstList">
 <tr>
  <s:iterator var="second" status="heads" value="secondList">

   <td>
     <s:property value="<s:property value="heading"/>"/>

   </td>

  </s:iterator>

 </tr>

</s:iterator>
```

[image]

Is it possible to give the property value dynamically...
 here the value is a variable which is increments dynamically.....

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What is `heading`? Are you trying to evaluate `heading`?